# Navigation Drawer MenuAdapter Naming

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've been following the tutorial below to try to learn how to properly use the Navigation Drawer Menu for Android:

> http://gmariotti.blogspot.ca/2013/05/creating-navigation-drawer.html
>   https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/androiddev/tree/master/NavigationDrawer

However - I have been trying to change the name of the items in the NavigationDrawer Menu within the array "ns_menu_items" in arrays.xml.

I don't understand how the MainMenu is converting these menu item names into ids because the sample application keeps crashing when I try to run the application if I change the names.

arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="ns_menu_items">
        <item>ns_menu_snippet1</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet2</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet3</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet4</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet5</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet6</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet7</item>
    </string-array>

    <array name="ns_menu_items_icon">
        <item>ic_action_settings</item>
        <item>ic_save</item>
        <item>action_add</item>
        <item>ic_launcher_</item>
        <item>action_add</item>
        <item>ic_action_settings</item>
        <item>ic_launcher_</item>
    </array>

</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private ListView mDrawerList;
        private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
        private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        private String[] menuItems;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

                // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
                getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

                mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

                // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
                // opens
                mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

                _initMenu();
                mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
                mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        }

        private void _initMenu() {
                NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);

                // Add Header
                mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header);

                // Add first block

                menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                                R.array.ns_menu_items);
                String[] menuItemsIcon = getResources().getStringArray(
                                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);

                int res = 0;
                for (String item : menuItems) {

                        int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                                        this.getPackageName());
                        int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[res],
                                        "drawable", this.getPackageName());

                        NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
                        if (res==1) mItem.counter=12; //it is just an example...
                        if (res==3) mItem.counter=3; //it is just an example...
                        mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
                        res++;
                }

                mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header2);

                mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
                if (mDrawerList != null)
                        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
                super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
                mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_save).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                /*
                 * The action bar home/up should open or close the drawer.
                 * ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
                 */
                if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                        return true;
                }

                // Handle your other action bar items...
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

                public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout){
                        super(
                            mActivity,
                            mDrawerLayout, 
                            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                            R.string.ns_menu_open, 
                            R.string.ns_menu_close);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_close));
                        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_open));
                        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }
        }

        private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
                        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
                        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                String text= "menu click... should be implemented";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //You should reset item counter 
                mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

                }

        }

}
```

NsMenuAdapter.java

```
public class NsMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NsMenuItemModel> {

        /*
         * public NsMenuAdapter(Context context, int resource, int
         * textViewResourceId, String[] objects) { super(context,
         * R.layout.ns_menu_row, textViewResourceId, objects); }
         */

        public NsMenuAdapter(Context context) {
                super(context, 0);
        }

        public void addHeader(int title) {
                add(new NsMenuItemModel(title, -1, true));
        }

        public void addItem(int title, int icon) {
                add(new NsMenuItemModel(title, icon, false));
        }

        public void addItem(NsMenuItemModel itemModel) {
                add(itemModel);
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
                return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                return getItem(position).isHeader ? 0 : 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                return !getItem(position).isHeader;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder {
                public final TextView textHolder;
                public final ImageView imageHolder;
                public final TextView textCounterHolder;

                public ViewHolder(TextView text1, ImageView image1,TextView textcounter1) {
                        this.textHolder = text1;
                        this.imageHolder = image1;
                        this.textCounterHolder=textcounter1;
                }
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                NsMenuItemModel item = getItem(position);
                ViewHolder holder = null;
                View view = convertView;

                if (view == null) {
                        int layout = R.layout.ns_menu_row_counter;
                        if (item.isHeader)
                                layout = R.layout.ns_menu_row_header;

                        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layout, null);

                        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_title);
                        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_icon);
                        TextView textcounter1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_counter);
                        view.setTag(new ViewHolder(text1, image1,textcounter1));
                }

                if (holder == null && view != null) {
                        Object tag = view.getTag();
                        if (tag instanceof ViewHolder) {
                                holder = (ViewHolder) tag;
                        }
                }


            if(item != null && holder != null)
            {
                    if (holder.textHolder != null)
                                holder.textHolder.setText(item.title);

                    if (holder.textCounterHolder != null){
                            if (item.counter > 0){
                                    holder.textCounterHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.textCounterHolder.setText(""+item.counter);
                            }else{
                                    holder.textCounterHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                        }

                if (holder.imageHolder != null) {
                                if (item.iconRes > 0) {
                                        holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        holder.imageHolder.setImageResource(item.iconRes);
                                } else {
                                        holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                        }
            }

            return view;                
        }

}
```

NsMenuItemModel.java

```
public class NsMenuItemModel {

        public int title;
        public int iconRes;
        public int counter;
        public boolean isHeader;

        public NsMenuItemModel(int title, int iconRes,boolean header,int counter) {
                this.title = title;
                this.iconRes = iconRes;
                this.isHeader=header;
                this.counter=counter;
        }

        public NsMenuItemModel(int title, int iconRes,boolean header){
                this(title,iconRes,header,0);
        }

        public NsMenuItemModel(int title, int iconRes) {
                this(title,iconRes,false);
        }



}
```

Logcat Error:

```
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:239)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3844)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at com.example.navtest.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:702)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-03 23:20:09.124: E/AndroidRuntime(801):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone explain this to me? Thanks

Comment: pls post the code here

Comment: posted the code, i hope it helps

Comment: posted the logcat too

Comment: looks you have a resource not found exception. check your getview where you set the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
 holder.textHolder.setText(String.valueOf(item.title));
```

getting `Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0` because you are passing Integer to `TextView.setText` method

Comment: you are right. `public int title;` it looks for  resource with the id metioned if not found gives resource not found exception.